# Conditional search, match, filter and replace values between data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have two dataframes as shown below. I would like to replace values (cells) in dataframe 1 with NA if the corresponding value in dataframe 2 is below (or above) a threshold, for example, <= 0.05. I have tried to give a simple example below. I have some limited experience with R but cant think of an easy solution right away. Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated.

`input_1 = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                     col2 = c(1.2, 1.6, 1.9, 0.8),
                     col3 = c(2.1, 0.8, 2.8, 1.9))`

`input_2 = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                     col2 = c(0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.03),
                     col3 = c(0.05, 0.06, 0.08, 0.07))`

`output = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                    col2 = c(NA, NA, 1.9, 0.8),
                    col3 = c(2.1, NA, NA, NA))`

Comment: Are your dataframes allways in the correct order, meaning that all corresponding rows and collumns are in the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just the indexing with base `R` this can be done with one line as the following. Before that, I recommend you use `stringsAsFactors = F` inside the `data.frame` function, this is also a good practice for future data reading into `R`.

```
input_1[-1][input_2[-1] > 0.05] = NA
```

It changes the `input_1` on place, but if you want to retain the original as is, then you can create another object beforehand.  `[-1]` excludes first column.

Comment: Thank you very much. Easiest solution (for me!). Takes care of the entire dataframe at once. Some of my dataframes has dozens of columns so it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest and easiest solution that I can think of for your particular problem is to use the `which()` function. The solution is:

```
output[which(input_2$col2 > 0.05),2] <- NA
output[which(input_2$col3 > 0.05),3] <- NA
```

The `which()` function finds the indexes `TRUE` values in a logical vector or array. By setting up a column(`input_2$col2`) logically against a value, `R` tests this hypothesis on all values in the vector and returns a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` for every value in the vector. When you combine this with the `which()` function and use in a subset of a vector or column/row in a dataframe, you'll get the values from that vector/column/row which fits your logical test. That is an easy way to set conditional values in a dataframe.

However, if you only have one threshold per column, then you can use `ifelse()` function inside a `mutate()` function that you pipe to your dataframe. Here's an example:

```
threshold <- 0.5
df <- input_1 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(col2 > threshold, NA, col2))
```

Hope that helps. If you are curious about `R` then read Hadley Wickham's book here:
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Base R approach, not very efficient

```
dt <- merge(input_1, input_2, by = 'col1', suffixes = c('_1', '_2'))
dt$col2_1[dt$col2_2 <= 0.05] <- NA
dt$col3_1[dt$col3_2 <= 0.05] <- NA

dt$col2_2 <- NULL
dt$col3_2 <- NULL

  col1 col2_1 col3_1
1  ex1    1.2     NA
2  ex2    1.6    0.8
3  ex3     NA    2.8
4  ex4     NA    1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = input_1
output[input_2[,"col2"] > 0.05 , "col2"] = NA
output[input_2[,"col3"] > 0.05 , "col3"] = NA

> output
  col1 col2 col3
1  ex1   NA  2.1
2  ex2   NA   NA
3  ex3  1.9   NA
4  ex4  0.8   NA
```